# Syntax of mac2vlan file in freeradius?

Tags: freeradius

Below is the content of mac2vlan file in freeradius.
When I uncomment this line `00:01:02:03:04:05,VLAN1` it logs a parsing error 
including configuration file /etc/raddb/modules/mac2vlan

```
/etc/raddb/modules/mac2vlan[10]: Parse error after "00:01:02:03:04:05"
Errors reading /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
```

What is the correct syntax?

```
# -*- text -*-
#
#  $Id$

#  A simple file to map a MAC address to a VLAN.
#
#  The file should be in the format MAC,VLAN
#  the VLAN name cannot have spaces in it, for example:
#
        00:01:02:03:04:05,VLAN1
#       03:04:05:06:07:08,VLAN2
#       ...

passwd mac2vlan {
        filename = ${confdir}/mac2vlan
        format = "*VMPS-Mac:=VMPS-VLAN-Name"
        delimiter = ","
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since this was posted, but for the next guy (or gal) that stumbles across this posting looking for help as I did, hopefully will find value in my answer.

The `/etc/raddb/modules/mac2vlan` file only shows an example of what the mac2vlan file should look like.

The actual mac2vlan file is referenced in this script:

```
filename = ${confdir}/mac2vlan
```

You should have (or create as I had to) a mac2vlan file in `/etc/raddb`/ using the syntax referenced above. Do not uncomment anything in `/etc/raddb/modules/mac2vlan` file.

I should also mention, that the version of freeradius I am using, the path is actually `/etc/freeradius` not `/etc/raddb` as referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is complaining about a line with a comment, which is missing a `#` character at the start of the line. Additionally, the last line probably shouldn't have been a comment, so the `#` character on the last line need to be removed.

Comment: Trust me that  is not the reason.

Comment: @EdikMkoyan Then edit your question, such that it is clear exactly what is in each configuration file.